# CSP violation despite using the correct meta tag

Tags: javascript

Below is the meta tag that I've included in the header in order to bypass CSP and allow the 'axios' cdn script:

```
block append head
  meta(http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy", content=" script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.2/axios.min.js")
```

However, I get the following error

```
Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.2/axios.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```